# How to use Azure function V3 with Entity Framework 6 (exception System.Data.SqlClient: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform)?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

I have an Azure V3 app that must call DAL repos built on Entity Framework 6.4
On database initialize I am getting an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

That is coming from: `System.Data.SqlClient` 4.8

```
public sealed partial class SqlConnection : System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.ICloneable
{
    public SqlConnection() 
    { 
        throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient)
    }
}
```

In similar threads the resolution was to downgrade `System.Data.SqlClient` to version 4.5.1, but in my case the dependency being added by Entity Framework.

Anyone having an idea if it is possible to use Entity Framework 6.4 in Azure function V3 app?

Comment: I literally first experienced this problem 5 min ago, so I am anxious to see the response.

Comment: In my case I have an Entity Framework 6.4 data model project, my Azure Functions project is v3 targeting .NET Core3.1.  I have also tried downrevving the function target to v2 and .NET Core 2.1.  All have same result.

Comment: Suggest you also include your platforms/targets.

Comment: Hi @Matthew I was able to fix an issue with the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it's still a .NET Core 3.0 SDK bug and the following is [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370#issuecomment-545655510) you could refer to.

Right click on Function project and edit `<FunctionAppName>.csproj`, add items below to copy related assemblies to output dir.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you'd like to stilluse the .NET Core 3.0 SDK, or need this fix for Functions v3 as well:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <!-- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568#issuecomment-461182536 -->
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(OutDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <!-- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568#issuecomment-461182536 -->
    <Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(PublishDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
    <!-- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/333 -->
    <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: @Joey I was excited about this solution as I'd previously read about the workaround but the System.Data.SqlClient assembly already existed in my output directory.  I added this item group but it didn't change the result.  I tried with 4.5.1, 4.6 and 4.8 DLLs.

Comment: @Joey So...  I directly added the Entity Framework 6.4 nuget to the project that consumes my data model project and boom, works.  I am still trying to understand dependencies in .NET Core/.NET Standard because the way it works isn't matching my current mental model. I'd have expected this EF 6.4 dependency to be resolved automatically given that I reference the data model project which has that nuget installed, but oh well, I've got to RTFM.